# Angular 14: Object is of type 'unknown' in ngFor since update

Tags: angular, typescript

Updated my project to angular 14.0.4

In the html of a component I have the following:

```
<div class="file" *ngFor="let file of localDocumentData.files; index as i;">
      <div class="card">
           <img src={{file.thumbnail}} alt={{file.file_name}}>
           <p>{{file.file_name}}</p>
           <p>{{ file.file_size | bytes: false }}</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

All the object properties in te ngFor loop have been highlighted with the following error

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.ngtsc(2571)
```

The files array is pulled in from an API as part of an object, in the ts file the file object is initialised as:

```
localDocumentData: any;
```

The project still builds locally without any issues but it's still highlighting the code.

[Screenshot of the highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaK4d.png)

tsconfig.json

```html
/* To learn more about this file see: https://angular.io/config/tsconfig. */
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question the `ts.config` file? Also, try to simply type your `localDocumentData` variable.

Comment: Added the tsconfig, I will try strict typing.

Comment: "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false, was added to try to fix the problem

Comment: I believe that the error is caused by `strictTemplates: true`. It should be set to true anyway. I believe since you have declared your variable as an `any` type, the interpreter doesn't know what `files` is. Try assigning an interface to your variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to redefine a proper interface type for your variable localDocumentData.

From what I see it should look like that :

```js
interface DocumentData{
  files:File[];
}

interface File{
  file_name:string;
  file_size:number;
}

localDocumentData:DocumentData;
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is not possible to define a type you can use $any:

```
<div class="file" *ngFor="let file of $any(localDocumentData).files; index as i;">
      <div class="card">
           <img src={{file.thumbnail}} alt={{file.file_name}}>
           <p>{{file.file_name}}</p>
           <p>{{ file.file_size | bytes: false }}</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```